# Can i make the back button load from cache?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, progressive-web-apps

I am working on a project that shows a list of posts. At the end of the list, there is a button to load more posts, this button will load 12 more posts to the bottom of the list through Ajax.

I am having what seems like a very common issue, but one that I, after searching for a few days, could not find the solution to, thus I am asking here.

**The scenario:**

Users will click on the button to load more posts, it doesn’t really matter how many times they do this, but let’s say for example sake that they click enough times to load 100 more posts, and then they decide to click on a post to read the full post.

**The issue:**

Now is the issue. When the users click the Back button, they will get back to the posts list, but, the posts list will reload the page as a “new” request, not showing the already loaded 100+ posts from the previous encounter with the page.
This means that if someone clicked on a post and wants to go back to the same place they were at, they will have to keep scrolling to the bottom and clicking on the “Load more posts” button many times until they get back to where they were.

**The goal:**

What I want to achieve is that the users will click the back button, and the browser will send the users back to the same location they were at, including scroll position (which it seems to already do) and the number of posts that were already loaded - basically, send them back to the posts list as they left it.

**What to do?**

I could update the URL each time the “Load more” button is clicked with the number of posts that have been shown or the number of times the button was clicked, and then when the users go back, to load either the same amount of posts based on the URL, or the post “position” (skipping x amount of posts to get to the same “position” they were in), but this could either lead to a very large HTTP request (loading a hundred posts at once, or more if they loaded more) or, when the user scrolls back up they would have to click another button to load previous posts, which is just another button that I prefer not to add due to the purpose of the website.

Ideally, the back button would load a cached version of the page, that way it will lead to the same scroll position, the same content will be loaded, and it won’t involve a new HTTP request - it will show the page as it was when they left it.

Also:

The website uses PWA, not sure if this helps at all, but just FYI since it has some caching options.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I would propose using `localStorage`.

Since the HTTP request already done. why not write the data into `localStorage` for future use.

my proposition would be saving the data in `localStorage`, on each page load of the posts page, you'll make 1 request to your server. you will then check if you have a matching entry in your `localStorage`. fi yes this means your `localStorage` data is up to date to the server posts list, then when the `loaded` variable increases you'll load more from your `localStorage` till all posts from `localStorage` are shown you'll then go back to making HTTP requests to the server for more posts and saving them in `localStorage`

to add the desired behavior of loading the posts when the user goes back to the page, `loaded` variable should be read from URL params onload

Comment: So this means that when the users go back to the list of posts, they will still need to scroll down and click on the load more button until they load all of the posts as they loaded before they left the posts list, correct? This solution will fix only the HTTP requests, right?

Comment: no, if the loaded parameter is available in the URL (http://localhost:2000/posts?loaded=20 for example) , you will use that param to know how many posts you will load

Comment: Ok, I understand. It's an interesting idea, though, I am not very familiar with localStorage but from what I understand, I would store the data of each post as key => value, meaning, for each of the 100 posts (assuming the user loaded 100) I would have to save each of the posts data pieces (post title, post content, posters id, posters profile image, etc.) that are outputted as key => value, and then when the user clicks back, get that data, loop through it and create the elements with javascript to output the posts?

Comment: yes, however you need to make sure that the data you have on localStorage is up to date  (no new posts were released), thus you make that HTTP request i mentioned to find whether localStorage is up to date or no

Comment: ok, I understand. Thanks for this. I still wonder if there is a way to utilize cache though since it seems like that would be the easiest way. I will need this same functionality to be applied to a few other places, and the items could change, which means setting up the localStorage for all these different lists (say a posts list, profiles list, and others), and if there are any changes to what is outputted, I would need to update the localStorage scripts to be up to date each time. So I wonder if there is an easier way to do it.

Comment: the other alternative is using a serviceWorker, serviceWorkers allow you to implement caching logic. here is a link to the popular strategies https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-strategies however i could not think of an implementation that would satisify your needs solely using serviceWorkers and caching

Comment: I do have a serviceWorker but I have not found a solution that works with it yet. But thanks for your suggestions, I`ll do more research on them and try and implement them.